# Using mv/cp to replace a invalid symlink with directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, unix, symbolic-link

I have a symlink at `/tmp/bot`  which I want to replace with a directory. But I am getting error

```
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory '/tmp/bot' with directory 'log'
```

Steps to reproduce error

```
# Create a symlink
$ln -s bot/ /tmp/bot
$ mv log /tmp/bot
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory '/tmp/bot' with directory 'log'
$ mv -f log /tmp/bot
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory '/tmp/bot' with directory 'log'
$ cp -r log/ /tmp/bot
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory '/tmp/bot' with directory 'log/'
$ cp -rf log/ /tmp/bot
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory '/tmp/bot' with directory 'log/'
```

It's simple but I can't get it done.
One option is to remove /tmp/bot and then move direcotry. 
But I want to understand if it can be done using mv
I am using `ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: I'm getting another error: `Too many levels of symbolic links`. This is because `/tmp/bot` is a symlink to `bot/` in the `/tmp/` directory; so it's a symlink to itself. I note I get `cannot overwrite non-directory` when I use `mv -T`. My `mv` is from GNU coreutils 8.30.

Comment: Pranjal Doshi : You are trying to create /tmp/bot/ which already exists. To make a link when there is no /tmp/bot/ : `ln -s [full-path-to-bot]/bot/ /tmp/`

Comment: Why are you using `mv` and `cp` when the tool you want is `rm`?

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to understand if it can be done using mv

As far as `mv` and `cp`'s man pages go, you can't. You'll have to use `rm` first.